# UITableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths: breaks scrollToTop / scrolling behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a tableView which can append data loaded from a web server when the content reaches the bottom edge.
For the sake of simplicity, let's assume the tableView stays fixed (no scrolling) until the web-loading is finished.

To insert new cells, i first update the dataSource (Array of objects) and then call `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:` with the newly added cell-indexPaths.

What i noticed is the following:

__BEFORE_APPEND

- "scrollToTop" feature works as expected (status bar tap) and scrolls all the way to the top.

__AFTER_APPEND

- "scrollToTop" does NOT work anymore. The tableView scroll upwards (content goes down), but stops below the very top at round about the space appended at the bottom.
- `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:` causes the tableView to scroll downwards (content goes up)

Regarding the scrollToTop i already tried overriding `scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:`, returning `NO` and doing the scrolling manually by calling `[setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -tableView.contentInset.top)]` on the tableView. <- leaves me with the same result.

It seems to me that inserting rows breaks the contentSize so that after the insertions (or deletions) the scrollView does not know how big it actually is !?

Is anyone seeing the same issue ?

How can i insert rows (without calling `reloadData`) so that the scrollToTop feature does work afterwards + the scrollView stays at the exact position it was before the insertion.

When appending items in a UICollectionView + custom layout, the scrollToTop feature does not break. However, the scrolling caused by insertions appears also for collectionViews. <- BAD

Thanks for your help !

**-- EDIT --**

Some sample code:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];

[itemCollection addObjectsFromArray:addedItems];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:addedIndexPaths
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Explanation:
The code is executed in the networking callback.

`itemCollection` contains the items (dataSource) displayed in the tableView

`addedItems` is an NSArray containing the newly parsed items

`addedIndexPaths` contains indexPaths from `itemCollection.count -> itemCollection.count + addedItems.count` in the current section

Comment: you need to provide some sample code, unless you want to read bunch of guesses:)

Comment: there is not really much about it ... but see my edit anyways

Comment: I meant code in a broader sense:) there is clearly a bug somewhere, and since behavior you described does not occur normally, the only way to figure out the issue is by studying your code.

Comment: Ok, well it helps to hear that this is not normal behavior :). Are you sure about that ? I was wondering whether this might be a "feature" built-in to iOS7 ?

Comment: Unless your update caused less items to be shown (which I doubt from your code snippet) and if you don't suddenly changed shouldScrollToTop to NO. This behavior should not occur